# trigger y formato de fecha en función

Tags: plpgsql

estoy queriendo hacer un trigger donde registre un cambio o creación de un nuevo registro de una tabla. En la misma tabla (empleado) debo registrar la fecha de modificación bajo el siguiente formato "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm"; donde "updated_em" es el campo a llenar. Mi función que tengo es.

```
-- el formato que ME PIDEN es updated_em como VARCHAT(20).

ALTER TABLE table_empleado ADD COLUMN updated_em VARCHAR(20);

CREATE FUNCTION fn() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    
    INSERT INTO table_empleado(id, updated_em)
          VALUES(NEW.id, NOW());
    RETURN NEW
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Tengo una duda en donde debo registrar el formato de fecha (fuera o dentro de la función). Otra duda que tengo es en relación a la creación del nuevo campo "updated_em". Yo lo hice fuera de la función no sé si esté correcto. Espero sus valiosos aportes en mis dos dudas.

Nota: estoy en Postgres

Comment: Yo usaría un campo timestamp que guarde el timestamp y sólo me ocuparía del formato cuando lo vaya a mostrar, en la capa de presentación (o, si nos da pereza, en la consulta que obtiene ese timestamp). De paso, tienes una columna donde puedes hacer operaciones entre fechas y no estás sufriendo con unos varchar.

Comment: @Alfabravo si eso pensaba hacer pero sucede que tengo que hacer con VARCHAR. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues sí, como quien recibe es un varchar, tienes que darle formato al `NOW()` (que retorna un timestamp).

```
ALTER TABLE table_empleado ADD COLUMN updated_em VARCHAR(20);

CREATE FUNCTION fn() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    
    INSERT INTO table_empleado(id, updated_em)
          VALUES(NEW.id, TO_CHAR(NOW(), 'HH12:MI:SS'));
    RETURN NEW
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Gracias, y por ejemplo si quiero que no se almacene valores nulos, debería poner en ALTER la restricción NOT NULL?, o en la función? si es en la función, cuál seria el comando?

Comment: @FranciscoMinchalaFajardo son cosas diferentes. Si por diseño no debes guardar nulos, ponle la restricción a la columna para que no pase. Si quieres evitar la excepción en el trigger, puedes validarlo (pero NOW no va a dar null nunca jeje)

Comment: Gracias @Alfabravo!

Comment: @FranciscoMinchalaFajardo con gusto! Recuerda que, si la respuesta te resolvió la pregunta, puedes marcarla como aceptada.